# Projecting and Measurements

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, distance, measurements

I am looking to project all my data into [EPSG::2959](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2959) (NAD83 CSRS UTM 18N) as I am working out of Ontario, Canada. Every time I start a project I set the project CRS to EPSG:2959, and then begin to add data. I typically use OSM from "QuickMapServices" (QGIS plugin) as a basemap for all projects, and change the CRS of OSM to EPSG:2959.

At this point I begin adding data, which typically changes the project CRS to [EPSG::3857](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857) or [EPSG::4326](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326). I typically change the CRS of both the project (again) and layers at this point. I often 'Save As' the data to the correct projection.

My issue now comes when I use the measure tool after everything is in EPSG::2959 (NAD83 CSRS UTM 18N). The distance measured is always incorrect.

How can I fix this to accurately measure distances in EPSG::2959?

I will take any advice or change any steps in order to fix this issue.

This may have been asked before but it's causing me an incredible amount of trouble and I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: don't use an OSM base map if you want to control the project projection.

Comment: Even if the CRS is changed for the OSM base map?

Comment: Don't change the CRS of the basemap. Change the CRS of the project.

Comment: This actually did help me, thank you very much! I haven't tested it yet (aside from opening it up with a project CRS of 2959 and OSM at default) but it makes sense that this is the problem!

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Make sure you have disabled the setting in QMS to force OTF projection, and then set your project properties accordingly.

Map rendering performance will degrade a bit (at least until reprojected tiles are cached), but it is totally worthwhile to work this way.

See? Not a problem anymore:
[image]

Comment: OTF projecting is turned off by default, and so this doesn't seem to be the issue unless there is more to this?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your full setup, but this is the only way I know of that will force the project CRS to change when loading a web basemap. I can add any and all data I want to my project at this point without CRS changing, and with measurements being done properly in my project-defined CRS.